# Android SensorEventListener tap detection on desk/keyboard

Tags: android, accelerometer, sensors, tap

I'm trying to implement an app which can detect if the user is typing on a keyboard (or tapping on the table).

Currently, I'm filtering the noise from the sensor and I put some settings on the sensor like noise level cancel and how often the sensor can detect with a handler.

The problem is that if you tap harder, the sensor detects a single strong tap like multiple small taps (it has sort of a spring effect).

How can I correctly detect each individual taps?

[This is the output using debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUChw.jpg)

My sensorListener

```
        sensorEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {

        float previous = 0;
        private int tapCount = 0;
        String tapIntensity = "";
        boolean canDetect = true;

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            final float current = sensorEvent.values[2];

            if (canDetect){
                if (current - previous > sensitivity) {
                    canDetect = false;
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            canDetect= true;
                        }
                    }, frequency);
                    tapIntensity += "= ";
                    tapCount++;
                    taps.setText(String.valueOf(tapCount));
                }
                else {
                    tapIntensity = " ";
                }
                previous = current;

            }
            log(tapIntensity);
        }


        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

        }
    };
```